# How to remove Radgridview border line in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

[My window gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYxIq.png)

I want to remove that particular line from RadGridView. First, I tried borderthickness = 0 but that line is different. I'm getting confused on how to remove that line anybody give me the solution for this.
Thank you.

Comment: Brush is a... brush. Did you try borderthickness 0?

Comment: @Sudakar: Did you try to set the `ShowGroupPanel` property of the `RadGridView` to `false`?

Comment: Hi @mm8, ShowGroupPanel= false is working, and thank you for your response

Comment: @mm8, Yeah sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `ShowGroupPanel` property of the `RadGridView` to `false` to hide the top area.